# How to click on Dialogue type Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying out web automation and have come across this popup dialogue box that shows while infront of the main page of the site, I have tried the following webDriverWait command after viewing another similar problem but no luck

```
noSave = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cmbtv")
noSave.click()
time.sleep(10)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"))).click
#notNow = driver.find_element_by_class_name("aOOlW   HoLwm ")
#notNow.click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

and here is the HTML block from the site,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t8oe.png)

if anyone could guide me in the right direction, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.click` is a function, so it should be followed by a pair of parentheses like this: `.click()`.

If changing `.click` to `.click()` does not work for you, then identify the `button` with text `Not Now` and click on it. This is how you do it:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]"))).click()
```